# Generating highcharts in ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, highcharts

I have a problem using Highcharts libraries and ajax. I have created various charts with the Custom Visualization tool available in Jaspersoft Studio,  but this time i need to call a webservice which injects data in a table and parse the SOAP response before displaying the chart. 
The highchart code is called in the complete parameter of ajax. 
But when running the JasperReports report embedding the js module i've got the error "TypeError: renderer is not a function" as if the library is not visible from the ajax.
Also tried to include all the highchart code in a function and call it from the parameter complete but still the same.
Note that i've separated the web service call and the generation of the chart and it works. Except it is necessary to execute the reports twice as the first time it successully inject the data but immediately displays the chart which is then empty. (Script 2 bellow)

Thanks in advance for your help !

```
script 1:
    define(['jquery','highcharts-all'], function ($) {
    var url = "URL";
    $.ajax({
        url: url, 
        type: "GET",
        success: function  (data) {
                    var $xml = $( data ),
                    $result = $xml.find('runJobReturn').text();
                    console.log($result);
                    if($result === "0") {console.log("OK")} 
                                        else alert("FAIL")
        },
        complete: function (instanceData) {     

                var chart;
                var series0 = instanceData.series[0],
                main_data = [], // structure 
                ...
                            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                type: 'column',
                renderTo: instanceData.id   
                },
                credits: {

script 2:
    define(['jquery','highcharts-all'], function ($) {
    var url = "URL";
    $.ajax({
        url: url, 
        type: "GET",
        success: function  (data) {
            var $xml = $( data ),
            $result = $xml.find('runJobReturn').text();
            console.log($result);
            if($result === "0") {console.log("ok")} else alert("FAIL")
        }           
    });


    return function (instanceData) {    

        var chart;
        var series0 = instanceData.series[0],
        main_data = [], // structure 
        ...

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'column',
                        renderTo: instanceData.id   
                    },
                    credits: {
```

Comment: I think that you have not shown your whole code.

Comment: Yes here are just parts of scripts showing how i've managed ajax call and the creation of the chart, can you tell me if my issue is meaningfull ?

Comment: Probably the problem is with ajax synchronisatnion. Try to use that scenario: ajax1 -> callback -> ajax2 -> callback -> init chart. All funcitons should be called one inside second.